# Decimal Formatting is not working

Tags: java, decimal, number-formatting

I want to be able to make sure a number only has two decimal places.

E.G Area entered = 256.12345 so Area would be 256.12.

This is what I have:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "#,###,###,##0.00" );
double area = new Double(area.format(area)).doubleValue();
area = (double)(r*r);
```

Comment: where are you using `df`?

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using the instance `df`.

Change your code to use it instead of calling methods on `area` (which won't work, since primitives don't have methods):

```
double area = new Double(df.format(area)).doubleValue();
```

However, the formality of precision is more for printing purposes than storing purposes (`Double` will store it in the IEEE floating point standard for doubles, which may lead to imprecise floating point values).

To get around that, use a `BigDecimal` instead, with a precision of 2:

```
BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(area);
decimal.setScale(2);
System.out.println(decimal); // will print area to two decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you do it.

```
//formatting numbers upto 2 decimal places in Java
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.14));
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.1454));

        //formatting numbers upto 3 decimal places in Java
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.000");
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.14));
        System.out.println(df.format(364565.1454));
    }

}

Output:
364,565.14
364,565.15
364,565.140
364,565.145
```